# How to set the date and time for all entries in the directory /home/virt/

Tags: bash

How to set the date (01.01.2000) and time (00.00.00) for all entries in the directory /home/virt/ ?

Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is that simple as

```
for i in /home/virt/*; do touch -t 200001010000 "$i"; done
```

Or simpler :

```
touch -t 200001010000 /home/virt/*
```

(thanks jm666)

---

If you have `bash4` and want it recursive :

```
shopt -s globstar
touch -t 200001010000 /home/virt/**
```

Or more portable :

```
find /home/virt -exec touch -t 200001010000 {} \;
```

Comment: why not simply: touch -t 200001010000 /home/virt/* ?

Comment: Who asked that ? Not OP. But It's a good day, I will add it to my post =)